# Laravel put array into selectbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am facing some problems with my selectbox, where i will put all available categories into the

In my controller i am using this snip:

```
 return View::make("stories.add")
        ->with("title","Indsend novelle")
        ->with("categories", Category::all());
```

In my view i am trying to put all categories into the selectbox with this:

```
 {{Form::select("category", $categories)}}
```

I could make this, but that won't work, because Form::select has to be as an array?

```
@foreach ( $categories as $category )
    {{$category->name}}
@endforeach
```

What to do?

I have made this and it works, but it looks too ugly and not user-friendly, any suggestions?

```
  $test = Category::all(); $myArray = array();
    foreach ( $test as $o):
          $myArray[] = $o->name;
    endforeach;

    return View::make("stories.add")
        ->with("title","Indsend novelle")
        ->with("categories", $myArray);
```

var_dump:

```
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(Category)#36 (5) {
        ["attributes"]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "Alderforskel"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
["original"]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(12) "Alderforskel"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
["relationships"]=>
array(0) {
}
["exists"]=>
bool(true)
["includes"]=>
array(0) {
}
}
       [1]=>
   object(Category)#39 (5) {
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Bondage"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
["original"]=>
 array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "Bondage"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
["relationships"]=>
array(0) {
}
["exists"]=>
bool(true)
["includes"]=>
array(0) {
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel 3 or Laravel 4? You should only need to tag this with one.

Comment: In laravel 4, you should be able to use Category::all()->all() to convert the `Collection` into an array.

Comment: Call to a member function all() on a non-object

Comment: Do a `var_dump(Category:all());`. I suspect it returns an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is give `Form::select()` an array of category names and their ids. If you iterate over the categories, you can aggregate these and then pass them to `Form::select()`.

```
$categories = Categories::all();
$selectCategories = array();

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $selectedCategories[$category->id] = $category->name;
}

return View::make("stories.add")
        ->with("title","Indsend novelle")
        ->with("categories", $selectCategories);
```

Comment: Says that "pluck" doesnt exists.

Answer (score 9):

Use it this way:

```
$categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');

return View::make('....', compact('categories'));
```

And now in the view:

```
{{ Form::select('selectName', $categories, null); }}
```

Edit: Found in the docs [Query builder # Select](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects) Have a look to this

Comment: Hey are you sure that `Category::lists('name', 'id');` this is valid?
I don't know about `lists` function on query builder or model.

Comment: `lists` function is deprecated & replaced by `pluck()` as of Laravel > 5.2

Now you can do `Category::pluck('name', 'id');`

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is instead of using the with() function with the view put inside the controller function.

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

After this you need properly reconstruct the array:

```
$category = array();
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
  $category[]['id'] = $cat->attributes['id'];
  $category[]['name'] = $cat->attributes['name'];
}
```

now in the View::make()

```
return View::make("stories.add",array('title'=> "Indsend novelle","categories", $category));
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: Doesn't work. If more than 1 category it shows ID instead of the name, where the name should be in the <option ..> ie.  <select name="category"><option value="id">2</option><option value="name">Bondage</option></select>

Comment: sorry kim my mistake I made a change in the foreach loop please make that change in your script and I hope that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach suggested by [Israel Ortuño](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162876/laravel-put-array-into-selectbox/17163856#17163856)

I would only add a small modification, so that the select starts with an empty *"Choose from the List"* option by default.

```
$categories = array(0=>'Choose from the list') + Category::lists('name', 'id');

return View::make('....', compact('categories'));
```

Now the dropdown looks like this:

```
<option value="0">Choose from the list</option>
<option value="{whatever-the-category-id}">Category 1</option>
...
```